# Model changes in a multithreaded JPA application

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

i have an application with a gui and a list of stocks that are saved in a db. I use 1 EntityManager the whole time the app is running, for deleting, changing and adding new stocks. I have a thread that periodically grabs the actual stock courses of the stocks and saves them in the db. I use another entity manager in the thread (cause of thread safety). It looks like this:

```
 // grabbing the actual info and making actualStockPrice with it
 ....
 // adding the correct stock to the new stockprice
 actualStockPrice.setStock(stock);
 // Can't do the next line cause of duplicate primary key
        //stock.getActualStockPrices().add(actualStockPrice);
// Saving new price in db
stockPriceModel.saveActualStockPrice(actualStockPrice);
```

I have a button to show a table with all the saved stockprices of a stock. I fill the table with stock.getActualStockPrices() but because i never added the new stockprices to the stock, the table only shows the stockprices that were there at the start of the program. If i uncomment the stock.getActualStockPrices().add(actualStockPrice);
i get a duplicate primary key error as soon as i save the stock to the db, cause of the new found stockprice in the actualstockpriceList of the stock. So what to do :?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stock is already present in the database, it will give exception. To only save the changes to the existing entity, use `merge` to update it.

Also, configure EntityManager flush mode to `FlushModeType.COMMIT` as default is `AUTO`. Therefore `stock.getActualStockPrices().add(actualStockPrice)` causes to reflect the changes into database instantly.

You can manage the transaction manually to gain better control over reflecting changes in database : *begin transaction - database operations - commit/rollback transaction*.

Comment: I now ran into a problem with this. Say my program is running for a long time and amassed lots of stockPrices. If i now want to view them and i call merge on the stock it can take a very long time depending one the number of stock prices (e.g. a few seconds for ~1000 prices). So the longer i don't merge the longer it takes to merge them (makes sense). What can i do against this?

Comment: After you merge some definite amount of entities, you can call flush on entitymanager to reflect the changes explicitly at regular interval.

Comment: @ Nayan Wadekar But flush only synchronizes for the given time? If i view my stock Prices and say after a long time (few 1000 new prices) i want to view again, i will have to wait long again?

Comment: If after a long time there are 1000 entities accumulated to be added, its better to add them at regular interval or instantly on creation, therefore don't have to wait longer. I am not getting it clear, point out if went wrong.

Comment: My problem is that the stock prices are added in another Thread automatically with another entity manager. So my main Thread em only get's to know them when the user interacts in some way with the program. If he for example wants to view the stock prices i have to call merge from my main em. So the longer the user does nothing the more stock prices get's added and the more time will the merge take. The problem is basically that i can't merge regular cause then i would have to constantly interrupt the main Thread every time the other thread adds a new stockprice.

Comment: Instead of merging entities every time when stockprice is added,  you can do it at regular interval. Also can limit adding the entities, like after having 100 entities, merge them in database. So even if user returns after long time, at max there will be ~100 entities to merge & will take less time for response.

Comment: I understood what you meant. But wouldn't i then have to interrupt the main Thread cause i need to do it there cause of the thread-unsafety of a em? (That's the whole reason i use another em in the child Thread).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8566/discussion-between-nayan-wadekar-and-biene-maja)